# Installed snap app not appear on menu list, had to run 'snap run {app}'

Tags: 16.04, snap

I recently installed Inkscape on my Ubuntu using snap but the app did not appear in any ways that I can find. I had to use

```
snap run inkscape
```

to run the app.

Any idea how to find where the app is installed?

Comment: Be sure to tell the Snap author about the issue. It might work properly for them, so perhaps they don't know about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find the executable in the `/snap/bin/` directory. You can use the `whereis` command to find that out, e.g.

```
whereis inkscape
```

You should also be able to find the `.desktop` launcher for the application in the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory. Copy the associated `.desktop` file to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. Then you should be able to find the application in your dash or menu list.

Alternatively, you can create a `.desktop` launcher for the application by hand. For a simple one, for example for Inkscape, create a text file, say `inkscape.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/` and add the following lines

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Inkscape
Comment=Create and edit Scalable Vector Graphics images
Exec=/snap/bin/inkscape
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=Inkscape
```